# Stretch space between views in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView with a dynamic number of elements (The heights of the elements is not known in advance). If the heights of all elements is less than the screen height, I want to add equal spaces between the elements. Is there a simple way to do something like this?

Thanks!

CraniumRat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this class to add space dynamically to the recyclerview:

```
public class VerticalSpaceItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private final int mVerticalSpaceHeight;

    public VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(int mVerticalSpaceHeight) {
        this.mVerticalSpaceHeight = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent,
                               RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.bottom = mVerticalSpaceHeight;
    }
}
```

If you set up the list or the sum of the heights of all elements changes then also update mVerticalSpaceHeight.

Add this line:

`rv.addItemDecoration(new VerticalSpaceItemDecoration(PUT THE CALCULATED HEIGHT IN HERE))`